# i want to ask about a makefile syntax for correct include.

Tags: makefile, simulink

My question is about a makefile alternative syntax, Is this syntax

```
C_SRCS += \
./path/*.c*
```

equal to

```
C_SRCS += \
./path/file1.c \
./path/file2.c
```

and if is it not, how can i have my `*.c` files in a variable when i couldn't know the names ?

I ' m talking about Simulink generated source and make files.

Answer (score 1):

By [Wildcard function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html).

```
C_SRCS += $(wildcard ./path/*.c*)
```

Comment: Should there really be a second asterisk *after* the `.c`?